# back button not working in my application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the condition below in the code that `if currentindextab === 1` etc  to work as I checked it does not work as well

I have dynamic form where I get all the fields and tabs from the database using webApi

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

         var defaultLanguage = $('#switchLanguage').val();
         loadForm(defaultLanguage);
      

        $('#switchLanguage').change(function () {
            var selectedLanguage = $(this).prop('checked') ? '2' : '1'; // English: '1', Arabic: '2'
            loadForm(selectedLanguage);
        });
   
     });

    function KTCreateForm() {
        console.log('1');
        var stepperObj;
        var stepper;
        var formSubmitButton;
        var formContinueButton;
        var currentStepIndex;
        var validations = [];
       


        function initStepper() {
            
            console.log('2');
            //stepper = document.querySelector('#kt_create_account_stepper');
            stepperObj = new KTStepper(stepper);

            
            console.log('3');
            stepperObj.on('kt.stepper.changed', function (event) {
                
                console.log('4');
                
                currentStepIndex = stepperObj.getCurrentStepIndex();
           
                if (currentStepIndex === 1) {
                    debugger
                    formSubmitButton.classList.remove('d-none')
                    formSubmitButton.classList.add('d-inline-block');
                    formContinueButton.classList.add('d-none');
                } else if (currentStepIndex === 2) {
                    formSubmitButton.classList.add('d-none');
                    formContinueButton.classList.add('d-none');
                } else {
                    formSubmitButton.classList.remove('d-inline-block');
                    formSubmitButton.classList.remove('d-none');
                    formContinueButton.classList.remove('d-none');
                }
            });

            
            console.log('5');
            stepperObj.on('kt.stepper.next', function (stepper) {
                console.log('55');
                var validator = validations[stepper.getCurrentStepIndex() - 1];

                stepper.goNext();

                console.log('finish next');
               /* KTStepper.getInstance(stepper).goNext();*/

                if (validator) {
                    validator.validate().then(function (status) {
                        console.log('validated!');
                        if (status == 'Valid') {
                            stepper.goNext();
                            // KTUtil.scrollTop();
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                                icon: "error",
                                buttonsStyling: false,
                                confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                                customClass: {
                                    confirmButton: "btn btn-light"
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    stepper.goNext();
                }
            });
            
            console.log('6');
            stepperObj.on('kt.stepper.previous', function (stepper) {
                debugger
                console.log('stepper.previous');

                stepper.goPrevious();
                console.log('7');
            });
            console.log('0');
        }

        function handleForm() {
            formSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                // Validate form before change stepper step
                var validator = validations[2]; // get validator for last form

                validator.validate().then(function (status) {
                    console.log('validated!');

                    if (status == 'Valid') {
                        // Prevent default button action
                        e.preventDefault();

                        // Disable button to avoid multiple click 
                        formSubmitButton.disabled = true;

                        // Show loading indication
                        formSubmitButton.setAttribute('data-kt-indicator', 'on');

                        // Simulate form submission
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            // Hide loading indication
                            formSubmitButton.removeAttribute('data-kt-indicator');

                            // Enable button
                            formSubmitButton.disabled = false;

                            stepperObj.goNext();
                        }, 2000);
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire({
                            text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: false,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: {
                                confirmButton: "btn btn-light"
                            }
                        }).then(function () {
                            // KTUtil.scrollTop();
                        });
                    }
                });
            });


        }
        return {
            // Public Functions
            init: function () {
                //// Elements
                //modalEl = document.querySelector('#kt_modal_create_account');
                //if (modalEl) {
                //    modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalEl);
                //}

                stepper = document.querySelector('#kt_create_account_stepper');

                if (!stepper) {
                    return;
                }
              
        
                console.log('8');
                formSubmitButton = stepper.querySelector('[data-kt-stepper-action="submit"]');
                formContinueButton = stepper.querySelector('[data-kt-stepper-action="next"]');
                
               
                initStepper();
                handleForm();
                console.log('9');
            }
        };
    }


 
    function loadForm(languageId) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetForm", "Home")',
            data: { languageId: languageId },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                
                $('#dynamicFormContainer').html(data);

                
 
                console.log('before KTCreateForm');
                var formObject = KTCreateForm();
                formObject.init();

            },

            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching dynamic form:', error);
            }

        });
    }
```

issue is when I click continue the second tab is getting opened and and then I click back its not working

Comment: *and then I click back* - do you have a `back` button *on your form*?    Or do you mean click on the browser's *back* button?   When you click `next` does it change the url?  Do you have any code to handle the browser's back button?  (none provided).     If it's on the form, there's no code to handle it (in the provided code).   Can you change your ajax code to simply return dummy data and add some HTML, so we can see it in action?  See [mcve].

Comment: the bundle.js file not getting hit on an event what might be the problem

Comment: There's no mention of `bundle.js` in your question - please be sure to include *all* relevant code.  See [mcve]